# consultas en modelos django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo un problema que no se como resolverlo. Tengo en mi app tres modelos:

```
class Hecho(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    hecho = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Beneficiario(models.Model):
    tipoDocumento = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    numeroDocumento = models.IntegerField()
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class HechoBeneficiario(models.Model):
    beneficiario = models.ForeignKey(Beneficiario)
    hecho = models.ForeignKey(HechoVictimizante)
```

Como se puede ver el modelo `HechoBeneficiario` relaciona los otros dos modelos.

¿Mi problema esta como atraves del modelo beneficiario puedo llegar al modelo hecho y pintar esto en una `template`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso, tienes una relación [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) entre Hecho y Beneficiario. Lo ideal sería que definieras un campo en Hecho, por ejemplo, en el que pusieras algo del estilo:

```
class Hecho(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    hecho = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    beneficiarios = models.ManyToManyField('Beneficiario', through='HechoBeneficiario', symmetrical=False, related_name='beneficiarios')
```

De tal manera que accederías a los objetos

```
Hecho.objects.all().filter(beneficiarios__numeroDocumento="xxxxxxx")
```